# EOFException when I extract the Object Input/Out put Stream

Tags: java, java-io, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I use ObjectInput/Output to initialize the hashmap named temp and it put all entry of the hashmap called map that is initialized to new and then use OutputStream to save it in file formatting is .ser
this work perfectly...

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class PlayerInfo implements Serializable {

    ObjectOutputStream out;
    ObjectInputStream in;
    File userData =new File("path.ser");
    HashMap map ;
    HashMap temp;
    private Integer ID;
    String name ;
    boolean isItNull =false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PlayerInfo();
    }
    PlayerInfo(){
        try {
        initializeHashMap();

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void initializeHashMap(){

    try {
//initialize ObjectInputStream in same method when I use it and close it then
        in =new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(userData));

        if (isItNull){
            temp =new HashMap<Integer,PlayerInfo>();

        }else {
            map =new HashMap<Integer,PlayerInfo>();
            temp = (HashMap<Integer, PlayerInfo>) in.readObject();
            in.close();
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        isItNull =true;
        initializeHashMap();
    }

    }

    private void getInfo(){

        System.out.println("Ok we are in get info so write your ID:-");
        int id = 10;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void createInfo()throws IOException{
//same here initialize ObjectOutputStreamin same method when I use it and close it then
        out =new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(userData));

        System.out.println("Ok we are in create info so write your ID:-");
        ID =10;
        String scnS ="Mohammed";
        System.out.println("Write your name");
        map.put(ID,new PlayerInfo(scnS));
        temp.putAll(map);

        System.out.println("Saving....");
        out.writeObject(temp);
        out.close();
    }

    public PlayerInfo(String name){
        this.name =name;
    }


}
```

but this throw EFOException

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class PlayerInfo implements Serializable {

    ObjectOutputStream out;
    ObjectInputStream in;
    File userData =new File("path.ser");
    HashMap map ;
    HashMap temp;
    private Integer ID;
    String name ;
    boolean isItNull =false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new PlayerInfo();

    }
    PlayerInfo(){
        try {
        openTheOutPutObjectStreamer();
        openTheInPutObjectStreamer();
        initializeHashMap();

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
//here I initialize it in separated method 
    private void openTheOutPutObjectStreamer()throws IOException{
        out =new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(userData));

    }
//same here I initialize it in separated method 

    private void openTheInPutObjectStreamer()throws IOException{

        in =new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(userData));

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void initializeHashMap(){

    try {

        if (isItNull){
            temp =new HashMap<Integer,PlayerInfo>();

        }else {
            map =new HashMap<Integer,PlayerInfo>();
            temp = (HashMap<Integer, PlayerInfo>) in.readObject();
            in.close();
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        isItNull =true;
        initializeHashMap();
    }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void createInfo()throws IOException{

        System.out.println("Ok we are in create info so write your ID:-");
        ID =10;
        String scnS ="Mohammed";
        System.out.println("Write your name");
        map.put(ID,new PlayerInfo(scnS));
        temp.putAll(map);

        System.out.println("Saving....");
        out.writeObject(temp);
        out.close();
    }

    public PlayerInfo(String name){
        this.name =name;
    }

}
```

if you see it the difference is only separate the Object Input/Output to a method and call them 
and I am sorry I am a newbie in this website
I don't know a lot about IO but it seems like I cant separate it to methods and call it?

Comment: At which line are you getting the exception? What is the full error?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your first code you (correctly) open an input stream uses it and then closes it before doing anything else to the same file but in your second code version you also open the output stream on the same file before having read it and that output stream puts the marker (where to read or write) at the end of the file so when you use your input stream you get an End of file error.

Changing you code to this should work

```
openTheInPutObjectStreamer();
initializeHashMap();
openTheOutPutObjectStreamer();
```

Comment: so I can't open InputObjectStreamer and OutputObjectStreamer together?

Comment: No, not on the same file. Possibly there are other IO stream classes you can use for that.